# What is the difference between postgresql rebuild index and recreate index, which one is better?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.3

I have a table which index size is too big (about 2G). When I restore the database to a VM, the size is only 200M so I need  to rebuild/recreate the index and I will probably do this online.

What is the difference between re-building (reindex) and re-creating the index, and which one is better when I do it online? Particularly, which option allows querying the DB during the operation?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `REINDEX` command [requires an exclusive table lock](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/routine-reindex.html), which means that it'll stall any accesses to the table until the command has completed. If you can afford that kind of maintenance window it's perfectly fine.

The alternative for online rebuilding is to create a new index using [`CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/sql-createindex.html#SQL-CREATEINDEX-CONCURRENTLY), then drop the old one. This will take longer to complete, but allows access to the table while rebuilding the index.

Comment: thanks for you help. I find someone said "Postgresql supports creating two indexes on the same field, so we can use concurrently to create a new index and then delete the old index" is this a good solution?

Comment: That's absolutely fine, and I'd recommend it. I've updated my answer to reflect that.

Answer (score 2):

Postgres 12 has added a `REINDEX INDEX CONCURRENTLY` command, which does what you want here. https://paquier.xyz/postgresql-2/postgres-12-reindex-concurrently/ https://www.depesz.com/2019/03/29/waiting-for-postgresql-12-reindex-concurrently/